# Formally real field with two different orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

If $F$ is a formally real field, then there exists a total order relation on $F$ which is compatible with its sum and product, but it needs not be unique.

a) How different can be two (compatible with the field) order relations over the same formally real field, in the sense of not sharing important properties (e.g. being Archimedean)? Can you give specific examples?

b) Can the interrelation between two different order relations over the same formally real field be used for proving any interesting result?

Comment: Start with the real algebtaics, usual order. Add a real transcendental. On the resulting field put (a) the usual order or (b) an order that makes the transcendental larger than any real algebraic.  Some detail is needed, unless the relevant theorem has already been proved. (If $\alpha$ is not the negative of a sum of squares, then the order can be extended to make $\alpha$ positive.)  So this takes care of Archimedean. But apart from that, your question  is quite open-ended.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am just learning about ordered fields, and I was wondering which kinds of unintuitive behavior could lie under the definitions... but I don't even know about which properties should I care for, apart from being Archimedean (the only important result I now is that all ordered fields with the least-upper-bound property are isomorphic to the reals). Which interesting properties depend on the order? Are their different instances related somehow, so that we can exploit their relation to extract information about the field from two of its different orders?

Answer (score 4):

A simple example, $F = \mathbb Q(X)$.  For any transcendental real number $\alpha$, we can order $F$ be letting $X=\alpha$.  We can also order $F$ by letting $X$ exceed all elements of $\mathbb Q$.  Or with $0 < X < r$ for all positive rationals $r$.  There are others, too.

Answer (score -1):

I can just make you an example. For the zeromello's lemma in every set is possibile to impose a good order (such that every subsets has minimal element) which is very different from the standard order on R. So i belive that the answer to point a is yes order can have  really different propreties.

Comment: By "zeromello's lemma", do you perhaps mean "Zorn's lemma" or (equivalently) the well-ordering theorem (which is sometimes called Zermelo's theorem)?

Comment: Yes Patrick just has you sad